# SSL AWS Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

We have a machine on AWS where our site is hosted and we need to correct the security flaw for lack of SSL certificate;

in "Certificate Manager" I have generated a public certificate with the name of the site but I don't know how to get the site to recognize this certificate, I need help!

Note: it is not possible to generate a file (.cer , .pfx... etc)

Comment: The ACM certs can only be applied to something like an AWS Load Balancer or CloudFront distribution. You can't download it and put it directly on an instance. If you want a cert directly on an EC2 instance, https://letsencrypt.org/.

Answer (score 0):

ACM certificates can be associated with a CloudFront distribution or ALB. There's no way to export an ACM certificate / key for use on an EC2 instance.

If you don't want to use CloudFront / ALB you should get a certificate from an external CA such as [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). There are multiple different pieces of software that make it easier to request and install a LE cert, I'm not going to recommend one but the LE website probably has a list.